# Weird behavior of SMS app

Tags: android, sms

I'm developing an app that sends and receives SMS messages. The basic idea is to have one activity to handle the list of contacts that the user has messaged with, and one activity to view the conversation with a specific contact.
So the first activity is a list of contacts and when the user selects one, another activity starts, showing the conversation thread with the selected user.

What I did works **if the conversation is not too long**: in this case the conversation thread is succesfully shown. If, on the other hand, the conversation contains a lot of messages, the app loads for a while and then goes back to the list of contacts **adding the phone number of the selected contact to the contact list** or simply **goes back to the list of contacts**.

I don't understand why this is happening, I hope that you can help me. Here is the code:

### List of contacts

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class myActivity extends ListActivity implements onClickListener {

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> nameAndNumbers = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

/* here I find the phone numbers of the contacts from the SMS content
provider and then I find their contact name as saved in the address book */

Uri messagesUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(messagesUri,new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body", "type" }, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(cursor);
String[] columns = new String[] { "address", "person", "date", "body", "type" };
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    int counter = 0;
   while (cursor.moveToNext()){
       String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
       String contact=address;
       Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(address));  
       Cursor cs= getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},PhoneLookup.NUMBER+"='"+address+"'",null,null);
       startManagingCursor(cs);
       if(cs!=null) {
           if(cs.getCount()>0)
           {
            cs.moveToFirst();
            contact=cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
           }

           if (!names.contains(contact)) {
               /* this part is needed to make it so that the app
does not create two separate threads if the phone number comes with or without
international prefix code
                */
               names.add(contact);
               if (contact.startsWith("+1")) {
                   names.add(contact.substring(2));
               } else {
                   names.add("+1" + contact);
               }
               nameAndNumbers.add(new ArrayList<String>());
               nameAndNumbers.get(counter).add(contact);
               nameAndNumbers.get(counter).add(address);
               listItems.add(contact);
               counter = counter + 1;
           }
       }
   }
}
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    listItems);
setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String number = nameAndNumbers.get(position).get(1);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, myThread.class);
    i.putExtra("key", number);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

### Conversation thread

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class myThread extends ListActivity {

EditText txtMessage;
String phoneNum;
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.thread);

    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    String number = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
    phoneNum = number;
    list.add(number);
    if (number.startsWith("+1")) {
        list.add(number.substring(2));
    } else {
        list.add("+1" + number);
    }
    String[] smsNo = new String[list.size()];
    list.toArray(smsNo);

    Uri messagesUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(messagesUri, null,"address=? or address=?", smsNo, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String[] columns = new String[] { "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body", "type" };
    String sms = "";
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
       while (cursor.moveToNext()){
           String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
           String contact=address;
           Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(address));  
           Cursor cs= getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},PhoneLookup.NUMBER+"='"+address+"'",null,null);
           startManagingCursor(cs);
           if(cs!=null) {
               if(cs.getCount()>0)
               {
                cs.moveToFirst();
                contact=cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
               }
           }
           sms += contact + " ";
           String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
           sms += name + " ";
           String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
           sms += date + " ";
           String msg = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[4]));
           sms += msg + " ";
           String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[5]));
           sms += type;
           listItems.add(sms);
           sms = "";
       }
    }
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.sms_list_item,
            listItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

### LogCat

I'm pasting only error messages.

```
05-08 10:25:52.955: E/Mms(268): [1] Tried to add duplicate Conversation to Cache
.
.
.
05-08 10:27:32.865: W/dalvikvm(175): Last 10 entries in JNI global reference table:
05-08 10:27:32.865: W/dalvikvm(175):  1991: 0x40719248 cls=Landroid/database/CursorToBulkCursorAdaptor; (44 bytes)
05-08 10:27:32.865: W/dalvikvm(175):  1992: 0x40719248 cls=Landroid/database/CursorToBulkCursorAdaptor; (44 bytes)
05-08 10:27:32.865: W/dalvikvm(175):  1993: 0x406f8b38 cls=Ljava/lang/ref/WeakReference; (28 bytes)
05-08 10:27:32.865: W/dalvikvm(175):  1994: 0x406f4d98 cls=Ljava/lang/ref/WeakReference; (28 bytes)
05-08 10:27:32.865: W/dalvikvm(175):  1995: 0x406bfd08 cls=Landroid/database/ContentObserver$Transport; (36 bytes)
05-08 10:27:32.865: W/dalvikvm(175):  1996: 0x406bc5a8 cls=Landroid/database/CursorToBulkCursorAdaptor; (44 bytes)
05-08 10:27:32.865: W/dalvikvm(175):  1997: 0x406bc5a8 cls=Landroid/database/CursorToBulkCursorAdaptor; (44 bytes)
05-08 10:27:32.865: W/dalvikvm(175):  1998: 0x406809b8 cls=Ljava/lang/ref/WeakReference; (28 bytes)
05-08 10:27:32.865: W/dalvikvm(175):  1999: 0x406809f8 cls=Ljava/lang/ref/WeakReference; (36 bytes)
05-08 10:27:32.865: W/dalvikvm(175):  2000: 0x40612b68 cls=Landroid/database/ContentObserver$Transport; (28 bytes)
05-08 10:27:32.885: W/dalvikvm(175): JNI global reference table summary (2001 entries):
05-08 10:27:32.885: W/dalvikvm(175):    36 of Ljava/lang/Class; 164B (29 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.885: W/dalvikvm(175):    44 of Ljava/lang/Class; 188B (15 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.885: W/dalvikvm(175):     6 of Ljava/lang/Class; 212B (6 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.885: W/dalvikvm(175):    10 of Ljava/lang/Class; 236B (5 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.885: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 260B
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     4 of Ljava/lang/Class; 284B (2 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     6 of Ljava/lang/Class; 308B (5 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     3 of Ljava/lang/Class; 332B (2 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 356B
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     2 of Ljava/lang/Class; 380B (1 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 428B
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 452B
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 476B
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 500B
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 572B
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     2 of Ljava/lang/Class; 596B (2 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 692B
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 1004B
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 1172B
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 1316B
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 3452B
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Ljava/lang/String; 28B
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     2 of Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime; 12B (1 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):   724 of Ljava/lang/ref/WeakReference; 28B (724 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):    28 of Ljava/lang/ref/WeakReference; 36B (28 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Landroid/app/ActivityThread$ProviderClientRecord; 28B
05-08 10:27:32.895: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Landroid/app/ActivityThread$ApplicationThread; 28B
05-08 10:27:32.905: W/dalvikvm(175):     5 of Landroid/content/ContentProvider$Transport; 28B (5 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.905: W/dalvikvm(175):     3 of Landroid/app/LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$InnerReceiver; 28B (3 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.905: W/dalvikvm(175):     2 of Landroid/app/LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$InnerReceiver; 36B (2 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.905: W/dalvikvm(175):   345 of Landroid/database/ContentObserver$Transport; 28B (345 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.905: W/dalvikvm(175):    23 of Landroid/database/ContentObserver$Transport; 36B (23 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.905: W/dalvikvm(175):     2 of Landroid/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager$ControlledInputConnectionWrapper; 36B (2 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.905: W/dalvikvm(175):     2 of Landroid/view/ViewRoot$InputMethodCallback; 28B (2 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.905: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Landroid/view/ViewRoot$W; 28B
05-08 10:27:32.905: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Landroid/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager$1; 28B
05-08 10:27:32.905: W/dalvikvm(175):     1 of Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager$1; 28B
05-08 10:27:32.905: W/dalvikvm(175):   703 of Landroid/database/CursorToBulkCursorAdaptor; 44B (355 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.905: W/dalvikvm(175):    31 of Landroid/database/CursorToBulkCursorAdaptor; 52B (16 unique)
05-08 10:27:32.905: W/dalvikvm(175): Memory held directly by tracked refs is 73876 bytes
05-08 10:27:32.905: E/dalvikvm(175): Excessive JNI global references (2001)
05-08 10:27:32.905: E/dalvikvm(175): VM aborting
.
.
.
05-08 10:40:52.426: E/InputDispatcher(61): channel '407dd458 myApp/myApp.myActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
05-08 10:40:52.426: E/InputDispatcher(61): channel '407dd458 myApp/myApp.myActivityy (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
.
.
.
05-08 10:30:27.586: E/ContactsProvider(1309): Cannot determine the default account for contacts compatibility
05-08 10:30:27.586: E/ContactsProvider(1309): android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: bind failure
05-08 10:30:27.586: E/ContactsProvider(1309):   at android.accounts.AccountManager.convertErrorToException(AccountManager.java:1437)
05-08 10:30:27.586: E/ContactsProvider(1309):   at android.accounts.AccountManager.access$400(AccountManager.java:138)
05-08 10:30:27.586: E/ContactsProvider(1309):   at android.accounts.AccountManager$BaseFutureTask$Response.onError(AccountManager.java:1342)
05-08 10:30:27.586: E/ContactsProvider(1309):   at android.accounts.IAccountManagerResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountManagerResponse.java:69)
05-08 10:30:27.586: E/ContactsProvider(1309):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
05-08 10:30:27.586: E/ContactsProvider(1309):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: That's an odd bug. Can you post the logcat?

Comment: Maybe it's my poor reading comprehension, but I don't see either activity mention in each other's code, nor either in the logcat. Did I miss it?

Comment: @YusufX I'm sorry, I forgot to copy-paste the `onListItemClick` method in the first activity. This is where the parameter `key` is passed to the second one.

As far as the logcat is concerned, when the bug comes out, that's all the output I get.

Comment: @YusufX I've also added general error messages from LogCat (i.e. not those specific to myApp)

Comment: So I suspect that "Excessive JNI global references" is causing Android silently kill your Activity. You are perhaps directly or indirectly creating "JNI global references" proportional to the number of message.

Comment: @YusufX right, but I don't understand what I should change in my code to avoid this from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have JNI code (I'm guessing no), then you are running into an Android limitation and either (1) you're doing it wrong or (2 - more likely) you need to implement a workaround, such as loading a few messages at a time.

Comment: I don't even know what JNI is, so no :D the way I implemented it looks ok to me. Can you spot any blatant error in my code which might cause this issue?